# Find the probability that, on Tuesday, it does not rain in Greg's area and he does not get a quiz.

Tags: probability

> The probability of rain in Greg's area on Tuesday is $0.3$. The probability that Greg's teacher will give him a pop quiz in Tuesday is $0.2$. The events occur independently of each other. What is the probability of neither events occur?

My approach:

Probability of rain or quiz or both = $0.3+0.2= 0.5$

So, probability of neither= $1-0.5$ = $0.5$

Question: Actual probability of this problem is $0.7\cdot0.8$ = $0.56$. But, I don't understand what is the mistake in above approach?

Comment: They are **independent** not mutually exclusive.  For **mutually exclusive events** you have $Pr(A\text{or}B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$.  That is not true of independent events.

Comment: Principle of inclusion-exclusion 2set case: $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following two things:

> **Principle of inclusion-exclusion (2-set case)**
> $$Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$$
>
> **Definition of independent events**
>
> The following are equivalent statements
>
> - $A$ and $B$ are independent events
> - $Pr(A\mid B) = Pr(A)$
> - $Pr(B\mid A) = Pr(B)$
> - $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

For your problem: you know $Pr(A)=0.3, Pr(B)=0.2$ and they are independent, so

$$Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B) = 0.3+0.2-0.3\cdot 0.2 = 0.5-0.06 = 0.44$$

So the probability of at least one of the events occurring is $0.44$.  The probability of no events occurring is then one minus that, i.e. $1-0.44=0.56$.

---

Alternatively, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $A^c$ and $B^c$ are also independent.  We have then $Pr(A^c\cap B^c)=Pr(A^c)Pr(B^c)=(1-0.3)(1-0.2)=0.7\cdot 0.8 = 0.56$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach double-counts some possibilities. The $0.3$ covers all possibility of rain - so, it includes both "rain and quiz" and "rain and no quiz". The $0.2$ covers all possibility of a quiz, so it includes both "rain and quiz" and "quiz and no rain". So $0.3 + 0.2$ covers "rain and quiz", "rain and no quiz", "rain and quiz" *again*, and "quiz and no rain". To cut out one of the countings of "rain and quiz", we need to subtract the probability of that event, which is $0.3 \cdot 0.2 = 0.06$. So the probability of "rain or quiz or both" is $0.2 + 0.3 - 0.06 = 0.44$. The probability of neither is then $1 - 0.44 = 0.56$.